# RDP vs. VNC when looking them from security side

Tags: windows, rdp

Regarding: 

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12924/ssh-tunnel-with-vnc

Which one would be better, if we look it @security side? 
I heard that RDP is very very poor when it comes to security.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RDP has some issues, but these are broadly mitigated by getting the config right. Wicked Clown demonstrated a wonderful privilege escalation attack from restricted user to admin in less than 5 minutes at the recent B Sides London security conference which relied on a common misconfiguration - **[paper here](http://tombstone-bbs.co.uk/bsides/rdp%20issue.pdf)**. TLS can provide a strongly authenticated tunnel - which will help.

An alternative could be VNC - which also has potential issues, however using an SSH tunnel for this gives you a much better position with respect to security as you can use strong mutual authentication.

The key point to look at is what your key risks are - if you are worried about an attacker pretending to be a user, SSH or TLS with certificates gives you the authentication and encrypted tunnel part of the puzzle, is a good idea, however you still have the risk of an attacker stealing the mobile device:-)

Comment: so ssh tunnel+rdp... :( :\

Comment: or rdp+TLS ....

Comment: I don't trust RDP even if it would have a TLS feature.

Comment: @LanceBaynes can you provide a reason for not trusting RDP even with TLS?

Comment: I wanted to mean: RDP vs. OpenSSHD .... I think we don't need to compare the two on security side

Comment: @LanceBaynes, are you comparing apples and oranges?